# Animation Nodes extra nodes Morph between two objects with particles

Tags: animation, particles, animation-nodes

What would the setup look like to morph or get particles to form the shape of a mesh from another. Is it possible with the extra nodes that 3D Singh VFX has created.

Comment: It is possible to morph particles from mesh to another mesh or meshes or curve objects with Extra Nodes. I'll answer your question as soon as possible :)

Comment: Thank you your Awesome, much appreciated!

Comment: @3DSinghVFX did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was really busy with my studies. I'll answer this today. I have done a few months back but I'm making a simple example/node-tree for your question.

Comment: @3DSinghVFX Thanks so very much for your detailed explanation, and taking time out of your busy study life to help, greatly appreciated. Sorry for the delay had a family health emergency.
What I'm trying to do is very similar to what is described here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPCs4XbGth8) but without using the keyed particle setup and its limitations.

Comment: Is there a setup that will allow the particles to go from one mesh volume (or a number of mesh volumes) to another while that mesh is also animated, and then come to a resting state  that is more or less evenly spaced , similar to what the key particles allow for. Keyed particles can allow the mesh to be animated however it does not allow for transitions with animated meshes as described in the video, which is to manipulate them with turbulence etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about this, or if it is possible. Would you still need a particle system on each object to give the vector locations? I'm a bit lost and you r help guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so very much for all your help and time, once again greatly appreciated.

Comment: First thing I want to mention that you do not need keyed particles and also you only need one emitter object, the morphing objects (can have many meshes) can be two or three, anything and/or the emitter object itself. The Node-Tree which I mentioned in my answer morph the particles from one object (can have many meshes) to another object. Do you want to morph the animated text as shown in that video (you mentioned) or something else? By the way, I'll update the my answer for the animated object which has more than one mesh.

Comment: @3DSinghVFX thanks so very much for taking the time to respond and your help.
What I'm struggling with is to find a way for the particles after arriving at the second(or third) mesh settle and come rest without velocity and be distributed so the particles describe the volume of that mesh even if the mesh is animated. Does this make sense? Appreciate your expertise.

Comment: Your welcome. Okay, I'll update my answer soon :)

Comment: I have updated the answer for the morphing of particles on animated objects with turbulence force.

Comment: @3DSinghVFX This is outstanding! Thank you so much, I will let you know if I have any issues.

Comment: @3DSinghVFX ,Is there a good way to have the particles blow away after the third mesh, so to have a final transition  the particles fly away from everything or react to gravity if it is activated again. Is that not possible with this setup? Sorry for so many question, really appreciate everything.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I'll update the answer for the interaction gravity after the final transition but you can use any force, I have made several Forces-Group-Nodes which are easy to control https://youtu.be/bAQmewZSJQ4

Comment: I have updated the answer for the interaction of particles with gravity after the final morph transition. For easy understanding, I have used the existing Force field for gravity interaction.

Comment: @3DSinghVFX, Thanks so very much this is perfect. Thanks for all our help with understand this and creating these nodes.

Comment: if you satisfied with this answer, please press the green arrow.

Comment: Hey @3DSinghVFX, is it possible to have a mesh controlled by an armature and the particles be able to find the position of the animated mesh? Thanks again for your help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I use a model of a complex structure, say a wind turbine in my case I can't get the particles to be evenly spread out on the model. I have adjusted the scale value, which helps but it can't get the beautify results unless I just use simple primitives as your example. What could be the issue?

Comment: If I use 50000 particles things become very strange is that something that is a baking issue? Do I need to play the animation prior to baking, I'm using Blender 2.81.

Comment: I have made addon to bake particles in Blender2.8x (I have also mentioned in the answer): https://github.com/3DSinghVFX/Bake_Cached_Particles. Select the Particle Data Output then a Bake button will appear in the Tools panel. However, you do not need addon to bake particles in the Blender2.79x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

[image]

---

**Note-** Please watch the tutorials of Animation Nodes based particle-system for **[Blender2.79x](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvzr8lu5Ef0)** and **[Blender 2.8x](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pvX2_ZH1l0)** and **[Forces and other Group Nodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAQmewZSJQ4)**.

I am using Blender 2.79x for the morphing particles but you can also use the same node-tree in Blender2.8x.

---

**Edit:**

**Morphing particles between animated objects:** 
For morphing, we need random points on the mesh of the object that we will use for the locations of particles. So, I have made a **AN-Random Points on Mesh** group-node to scatter random points on the mesh using BVH nodes. You can adjust the seed, Amount (in this case is total particles) and scale, 
[image]

I have also made a **AN-Custom Delay Falloff** group-node which has easy controls (similar to keyed particle-system) for morphing transition between objects,
[image]

**Step-1:** I have added the particle-emitter Object A (Cube, *you can also use a separate object for particle-emitter*) and Object B (Cylinder) with animation on xyz-rotation,

[image]

The Emitter has these settings:

[image]

**Step-2:** Then add the **AN-Particle Input** group node which gives the necessary outputs (particle-system, locations, etc) and **Particles Output** node then connect the particle-system input, and also disable the **Always** execution option in the N-panel,
[image]
*(You can download extra **[Group Nodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAQmewZSJQ4)** if you need.)*

**Step-3:** Now we have to find the points/locations on the mesh objects (Emitter and Target) using **AN-Random Points on Mesh** group-node and Amount is the total number of particles:
[image]

**Step-4:** For the morphing effect, we have to Mix points (on the mesh, mentioned in Step-3) using **AN-Vector List Mixer with Falloff** which works similar to **Mix Vectors** node. Now, we can control the transition with any Falloff node,
[image]

**Step-5:** We have the resultant locations (or Post-Locations, after doing Step-4) and Pre-Locations, so we can calculate the velocities of the particles using **AN-Velocities From Locations** group node then connect the Post-Locations and Velocities to the **Particles Output** node,
[image]

**Step-6:** This is the final step, add the Falloff node which will control the morph transition. I have used the **AN-Custom Delay Falloff** node and set the Start Frame = 1, End Frame = 200 and Delay = 0.01 (you can change accordingly, e.g., to add some frames stay on some object),
[image]

**Step-7:** We can easily extend this node-tree for three objects transitions, here the third object is Object C (Ico sphere),
[image]

**Step-8:** I have used the **AN-3D Noise** group-node to add turbulence effect to the particles, and using Interpolate-node I have limited the turbulence effect during the transition, (two objects),
[image]

For three objects,
[image]

**Step-9:** After the final transition, to make the interaction of particles with gravity, I have added the **Force filed** and enable the **All** field weights in the particle settings. Then connect the **AN-Vector List Mixer with Falloff** group-node after the final object (in this case is Object C) to off the effect of final transition object and its falloff parameter is controlled by **AN-Custom Delay Falloff** group-node:
[image]

Three objects morphing of particles and interaction with gravity, the final node-tree:
[image]

Blend File for Blender 2.79x:

[image]

---

Blend File For Blender 2.8x (required **[addon](https://github.com/3DSinghVFX/Bake_Cached_Particles)** to bake Node-Based Particles):

[image]

[image]